# Resources for WPF designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, resources

I have the following structure of objects in my WPF application (simplified):

**Main window**

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedResources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedResources>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
                <local:MyEditor />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>

    ...
```

Then, **the editor**:

```
<UserControl>
    <!-- No resources here - getting styles from parent -->
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Resources in the main window are being managed dynamically (in certain circumstances I clear them and load another set to match theme of application), so I *cannot* embed the styles in `UserControl` (otherwise I would have to load styles in that `UserControl` dynamically as well). Of course apart from fact, that I actually don't even have to embed these styles in user control, because it will get them from parent.

But.

If I don't specify link to resources in XAML, the designer looks very sad (despite complicated structure of the UserControl):

[image: Empty designer]

Is there a way to provide information about related resources *for the designer only*?

Comment: Have you tried moving the default style to your App.xaml ?

Comment: @Aybe I can't. I'm developing a Visual Studio extension and I have no access to App.xaml :(